# Unable to connect remote docker host api from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am building a jenkins pipeline. It has stages checkout git project, build war, create docker image, push to a central repo.
Now my issue is I have to extend the stage to run the docker image in a dev server from Jenkins(Jenkins and dev servers are different machines). I am trying to establish a connection through

```
stage('Run') {
            steps {
                echo 'Running Docker Image.....'
                script {
                    docker.withServer('tcp://<host ip>:2375') {
                        echo 'Inside with Server'
                        sh 'docker info'
                    }    
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried below steps to expose docker api in dev server machine:
Edit the following file

```
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

And edited this rule to expose the API :

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -H tcp://localhost:2375
```

Reload and restart your Docker daemon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

I am getting below error

```
error during connect: Get http://<host ip>:2375/v1.38/info: dial tcp <host ip>:2375: connect: no route to host
```

Can someone help me understand why it is not able to connect to the host?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: coudl you test this url `curl http://<host ip>:2375/images/json`?

Comment: I think it must be 0.0.0.0 insteadof localhost to enable docker remote rest api

Comment: I tried curl http://<host ip>:2375/images/json still facing same issue curl: (7) Failed connect to <host ip>:2375; No route to host

Comment: tried 0.0.0.0 but getting same error

Comment: when you restart docker, is there any error?

Comment: There is no error. But i get msg: Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  docker.service

Comment: could you post the output of ths command `systemctl status docker` ?

Comment: is there any other way instead of withServer() would also help?

Comment: ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-10-01 02:05:07 CDT; 2h 44min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 9196 (dockerd)
   Memory: 21.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─9196 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
           └─9204 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/do...

Comment: level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
level=info msg="Firewalld running: true"
level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is ass...ddress"
level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=9094a76 g....0-ee-1
level=info msg="API listen on [::]:2375"
level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Oct 01 02:05:07 host_name systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

Comment: could you execute  `curl -v 127.0.0.1:2376/images/json` in  the docker host?

Comment: * About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 2376 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connection refused
* Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:2376; Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:2376; Connection refused
You have mail in /var/spool/mail/root

Comment: sorry, coudl you re-try with port 2375 and not 2376?